# create setup for a project with custom action to install Matlab software

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, vsto

I'm creating setup.exe for my project in VS2008.
But my project requires installation of Matlab also.

I want my setup.exe should 1st install Matlab software and then install my project.
I need to write code in C# and on Windows OS. How do i proceed with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you need Matlab runtime.
In that case check whether you can use an older Matlab 6.1 runtime. They require no installation you just need to copy the files under your application dir.
In case you wish to use a newer version I think you might want to try InstallShield which has a free version with VS (not sure about 2008)

Comment: using latest version of matlab